# Check if an element in a series is increasing with respect to the previous values in a series pandas, fast solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to check if elements of my series are continuously increasing.
For example if I have the following numbers:

```
[7, 15, 23, 0, 32, 18]
```

my output should be

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0]
```

If any value is greater than the previous value, then the output value will be output of previous value + 1, otherwise it resets to zero.

I have implemented a naive for loop solution in python, which is as follows:

```
def const_increasing(tmp):
    inc_ser = np.zeros(len(tmp))
    for i in range(1, len(tmp)):
        if tmp[i] > tmp[i-1]:
            inc_ser[i] = 1 + inc_ser[i-1]
    return inc_ser
```

But this solution is quite slow, as I am working with pandas series of large sizes. Is there any efficient way of implementing it ? Maybe using expanding() function or any better way in pandas or numpy.

Any help in this regard would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged `pandas`:

```
s = pd.Series([7, 15, 23, 0, 32, 18] ).diff().gt(0)
s.groupby((~s).cumsum()).cumcount().to_list()
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that does not use a cumulative sum:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([7, 15, 23, 0, 32, 18])
c = np.append(np.array([False]), (a[1:] > a[:-1]))
result = np.concatenate([np.arange(x.size)
                         for x in np.split(c, np.where(c == False)[0][1:])])
```